# Optimization problem with inequality constraints

Tags: calculus, optimization, constraints

Suppose we have $\theta=(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n)$, with $v_i:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ being a continuous, differentiable, concave function. Now I want to solve the following maximization problem:
$$
\max_{\theta} \sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i(\theta_i,a_i)
$$
subject to
$$
\theta_i\geq 0,\quad i=1,\ldots,n
$$
and
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \theta_i \leq c,\quad c\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
So far so good. We assume that $a_i$ is a negligible parameter and write down the Lagrangian and use the KKT conditions to derive the optimal solution.

But what if I want to consider $a_i$ as a variable of the objective function and also impose a constraint, that is
$$
0\leq a_i \leq 1,\quad i=1,\ldots,n.
$$

Can I still use the KKT conditions in this latter case? Would I have to define two Lagrange multipliers, one for each constraint? I am a little bit confused on how to do it.

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.